# Without UPnp and manual Port Forwarding, is it possible for a Router to listen on certain port?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, remote-control, upnp

#### Considering this set-up:

- Two houses with two separate Internet connections (thus, two public IP addresses).
- Behind the Router for each connection, there is a computer installed with [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en). Let's call computer A and B (Windows OS). Note: A and B connect to their corresponding Routers through Wifi or Ethernet; thus, [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) is used to access Internet.
- Using AnyDesk at one computer, connect to the other. The connection is smooth.
- In AnyDesk, there is an icon indicating that the Connection is **direct** ([explanation](https://support.anydesk.com/Settings#Direct_Connection)), meaning there is no need for a 3rd party server to relay communication.

[image]

#### Issue Description:

- It is guaranteed that [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) is **disabled** on both Routers.
- There is **no** intentional Port Forwarding configuration for AnyDesk, in both Routers.
- Using the tool [CurrPorts](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html), in computer A, I detected the remote public IP address and its Listening Port that AnyDesk (in A) is connecting to. This remote IP address is *surely the Router of computer B*.
- I double check with [Scan Port Tool](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), the aforementioned Listening Port is actually in Open State!

In my limited understanding of network, this is not possible! The Router of computer B, when receiving the network packet from Router of computer A, how does it know it should direct to computer B?

#### More

I killed AnyDesk process in computer B, and the Listening Port of Router of computer B was immediately closed.

In TCP/IP network, it follows [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model): *server opens a Listening port, waiting for connections from clients*.

Either there is a hole in my knowledge, or the Router of computer B gave false status (it says UPnP is disabled), thus AnyDesk (in B) negotiated with Router (of B) and opened the Listening Port!

Comment: Was it a TCP port or a UDP port?

Comment: @user1686 It's TCP port.